# MySQL BIT Data Type confusion

Tags: mysql

I have developed a database system utilizing MySQL to house some testing data.

```
CREATE TABLE testtable ( 
   TEST_IDX int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   PASS_FLAG bit(1) NOT NULL, 
   RESULT_STRING varchar(500) NOT NULL, 
   TEST_DATE timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
   LAST_MODDATE timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   TESTED_BY varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (TEST_IDX) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

One of the fields used is a flag to indicate the Pass/Fail Status of a test set. On my development machine I used the BIT data type, developed the database interaction code and tested the system successfully. I have a second development laptop that I used to perform bug fixes and such when deployment time came where the system also worked properly.

When I went to deploy the system on a production machine I set up MySQL and imported the database from a dump made off of the laptop. When the program, which had run successfully on both of my development machines, attempted to execute the error "data too long for column" was generated causing my inserts to fail. This doesn't make sense to me unless mysql has a setting that makes the bit/tinyint/int(1) behave in odd ways from install to install. I was able to make this function properly by simply setting the field to an INT (INT(11) it think) but I should not have had to do this and I would like to know why this happened. Perhaps someone could clarify how BIT data types work in MYSQL.

Comment: what is your `CREATE TABLE` statement? and what query are trying to execute when error?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `TEST_IDX` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PASS_FLAG` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `RESULT_STRING` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `TEST_DATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_MODDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `TESTED_BY` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TEST_IDX`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

The insert query is not generated by my software but rather by a module provided by National Instruments as part of the Labview Development Suite I am using.

Comment: so post your insert query that brings error

Comment: I have captured queries from MSSQL SERVER  but not from MySQL. What is the easiest way to capture queries in MySQL?

Comment: capture? what do you mean?